# Unit testing Spring Boot Rest Controller with JPA Repositories

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mockito, junit5

I have ,probably a basic question,related to unit testing a spring boot application that uses RestControllers,JPA repositories.Oracle is used in the backend.Now to unit test the JPA repositories using junit,mockito and probably DataJPA,do the tables that are present in the backend,need to be recreated in the H2 in-memory db?

Comment: The database should only be necessary for integration testing, not unit testing.

Comment: Yes. How do you create the tables in the Oracle DB?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. So annotations like @DataJPATest should be used only for Integration tests then. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry @Simon Martinelli,a little confused here.Based on the previous answer,looks like the tables need to be created in h2 only for Integrtaion testing.Not otherwise.

Comment: All this talk about unit testing or integration testing does not matter. If you have a database centric application then testing without the database makes only little sense.

Comment: I disagree @SimonMartinelli, why would I test that the database works as it should? The DB working is implied and expected as long as I feed it valid inputs. I can test my own code logic against mocks which is faster and easier to maintain.

Comment: @IgorFlakiewicz If you're only logic CRUD why should you mock the database? And what do you mean by "works as it should"? The logic with the database are the queries and you have to test if the queries work